# How to fix button clicked not updating but others do

Tags: swift

I'm making a math game. Every time I click a button a new question should appear with different results to choose from.

However every time I click the button which I think is the result it doesn't update the text but the others do.

See github: https://github.com/Combii/BrainTrainerSwift

[image]

Comment: David, I'm seeing (a ran the project) all the buttons change its number, could you be more specific

Comment: All change but the one you click does not change and keep on it's default state. The problem was you had to use btn.setTitle(String(number), for: .normal) and not labelText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIButton.setTitle(, for:)` method.  I suggest you to change code in `ViewController.swift`:

```
func setNumbers(numberDic: Dictionary<String, Int>) {
        let btns = [bt1, bt2, bt3, bt4]

        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            for (position, number) in numberDic {
                btns[(Int(position) ?? 0) - 1]?.setTitle(String(number), for: .normal)
            }
        }
}
```